# Get Current Customer in nopcommerce2.2

Tags: nopcommerce

Iam working in a nopcommerce2.2 project which is in mvc framework.I wanted to get current customer id in aspx page. can i get current customer info in nopcommerce2.2?

Comment: In ASPX Page? What do you mean? Look at WebWorkContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `new WebWorkContext().CurrentCustomer`

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency for IWebHelper to your constructor and use the CurrentCustomer property.